# Dot Product Numpy - Why can't I get a scalar?

Tags: python, numpy

I am having trouble understanding why the dot product in Numpy won't return me a scalar. I am trying to calculate the coefficients of a linear regression analytically using the below code:

```
import numpy as np

# Here the function is defined
def linfit(xdat,ydat):
    # Here xbar and ybar (the averages) are calculated
    xbar = np.sum(xdat)/len(xdat)
    ybar = np.sum(ydat)/len(ydat)

    # Insert calculation of m and c here. 
    diffx = xdat - xbar
    m = np.dot(diffx, ydat) / diffx**2
    c = ybar - m * xbar

    # Return your values as [m, c]
    return [m, c]
```

As an example I am using the following xdat and ydat:

```
xdat = np.array([[1],
                 [2],
                 [3],
                 [4]])
ydat = np.array([[2],
                 [4],
                 [3],
                 [5]])
```

diffx results in the following 4x1 matrix:

```
array([[-1.5],
       [-0.5],
       [ 0.5],
       [ 1.5]])
```

xbar and ybar result in 2.5 and 3.5 respectively.

The issue I am having is with calculating m. More specifically, calculating the dot product of diffx and ydat, which is also a 4x1 matrix.

The result I expect is a scalar, but every approach I try fails to return that:

1- `m = np.dot(diffx, ydat)` returns ValueError: shapes (4,1) and (4,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0). I understand the issues with the dimensions, but then why does the below work? (returns 3):

```
x = [1, 3, -5]
y = [4, -2, -1]
dot = np.dot(x, y)
print(dot)
```

2- I tried transposing ydat and get a 4x4 matrix:

```
m = np.dot(diffx, ydat.T)
[[-3.  -6.  -4.5 -7.5]
[-1.  -2.  -1.5 -2.5]
[ 1.   2.   1.5  2.5]
[ 3.   6.   4.5  7.5]]
```

3- I tried `m = diffx*ydat` and get:

```
[[-3. ]
[-2. ]
[ 1.5]
[ 7.5]]
```

4- I tried `m = diffx @ ydat` and get ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 4 is different from 1)

5- I tried `m = diffx @ ydat.T` and again get a 4x4 matrix.

The only thing that works is `m = sum(diffx * ydat)`, but Numpy simply won't give me the answer. I think I am missing something conceptual euther about Linear Algebra or Numpy here.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Make your xdat and ydat 1-dimensional, i.e., [1, 2, 3] instead of [[1], [2], [3]]. In that case, dot will behave as you expect. If you have 2D arrays, dot will try to do matrix multiplication. If you want to have "dot product" of two 2D arrays, you can call np.sum(array1 * array2); minor comment: sum / len = mean :)

Comment: You should use `np.squeeze` to remove dims of size 1.

Comment: Gosh I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can also use [`np.vdot(X, Y)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vdot.html), which does a dot product on any two arrays `X` and `Y` that have the same dimensions, no matter how many dimensions. For real numbers I believe it's equivalent to `np.dot(X.ravel(), Y.ravel())`.

Comment: `dot` and `@` have special documented rules for 1d arrays, so they return the scalar vector dot product.  For 2d arrays, the matrix product can be thought of as the vector product for all combinations of columns (of one argument) and rows of the other.